# Add unique constraint on two not null fields

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

I have an entity that contains the two fields:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
private Organization organization;

@Column(length = 15)
private String ref;
```

I want to add unique key on `organization` and `ref` this unique key will only be valid if the `organization` and `ref` are both not null.

For example when I insert two record where:

```
organization = 1, ref = 'R1'

organization = 1, ref = 'R1'
```

This will generate a constraint violation, so far I have no problem with this case.

And when I insert two record where:

```
organization = null, ref = null

organization = null, ref = null
```

This won't generate a constraint violation, so far I have no problem with this case either.

The problem I have is in this case :

```
organization = 1, ref = null

organization = 1, ref = null
```

Or

```
organization = null, ref = 'R1'

organization = null, ref = 'R1'
```

This both cases are generating a constraint violation, which I don't want, since I only want the unique constraint to be valid if only `organization` and `ref` are both not null.

This is how I declared the unique constraint :

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "organization", "ref" })
})
```

How can I solve this.

PS: I'm using Oracle 12c.

## Edit :

- Both fields `organization` and `ref` are nullable. The JPA
- @UniqueConstraint annotation I declared will generate the SQL code:

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "USERNAME"."UK_TABLENAME_1" ON "USERNAME"."TABLENAME" ("organization", "ref")

Comment: Is it possible to change the entity?

Comment: @pirho yes it is

Comment: why you not add constraint both `@NotNull` and  `@Unique` on both fields..

Comment: @AmolRaje Because they are nullable fields

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function based index for this.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_my_table ON my_table
  (CASE WHEN organization IS NOT NULL AND ref IS NOT NULL
        THEN organization || ref 
   END);
```

Comment: How this can be done using JPA, since my question is about JPA.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm) is rather strange about unique indexes:

> Ascending unique indexes allow multiple NULL values. However, in
>   descending unique indexes, multiple NULL values are treated as
>   duplicate values and therefore are not permitted.

So, you can handle this with a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_organization_ref on t(organization, ref);
```

The unique values should be ignored by the index.

Comment: That's the same query generated with the `@UniqueConstraint` annotation I delcared on my JPA entity.